# How to pass in a String to call an action form a Subclass in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, button, sprite-kit, subclass

I have created an `SKNode` subclass called `SpriteKitButton` which makes a custom "button" for use in `SpriteKit`, which I found here:

http://nathandemick.com/programming/tutorial/2014/09/23/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift.html

It works very well and I set up a button like so:

```
var page4Button = SpriteKitButton(buttonUnpressedImage: "page4Unpressed.png", buttonPressedImage: "page4Pressed.png", buttonAction: page4)
    page4Button.position = CGPoint(x: 210, y: 210)
    page4Button.zPosition = 1.0
    self.addChild(page4Button)
```

and it will call my page4( ) function properly. So my question is this: how can I modify my `SpriteKitButton` class to initialize by sending `buttonAction` the String "page4:" instead of directly telling it to use the function page4?

My goal is to be able to initialize `buttonAction` using string interpolation so I can make buttons with a for loop instead of making each one separately across many lines of code. I've never had to return something from a subclass like this before and I'm not really sure where to begin.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Hmm, I don't think Swift natively lets you map strings to closures unless you are willing to use some Obj-C. What I usually do in a case like this is re-use the action function and have the action  return the button that was pressed so I can check which button was pressed in a switch statement.

Comment: Hey Eric, how can I get it to return the button?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out! Changed () -> Void to (String) -> Void and returned the button.name property. I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't. Swift doesn't allow you to convert a `String` to a closure. However, you can create all of your buttons in a loop by passing each element in an array of functions as the button initializer's `buttonAction` argument.

First, define and initialize an array of `()->Void` functions

```
let actions:[()->Void] = [page1,page2,page3]
```

Then, create the buttons in a loop by passing each array element as the `buttonAction` argument

```
for i in 0..<actions.count {
    // Create your buttons here with actions[i] as the buttonAction argument

}
```

Lastly, define your functions/methods

```
func page1() {
    println("page 1")
}

func page2() {
    println("page 2")
}

func page3() {
    println("page 3")
}
```

Comment: That's a clever method that I didn't think of! Thanks 0x141E.